# Header height gets cut off in phonegap jqueryMobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have integrated an email plugin for phonegap. But, when i open up the email from the phonegap app, the header gets cut off. Here are the steps i follow :

[image: 1> The regular image, before opening up email. When the user clicks "Send Feedback, it goes to next screen."]

[image: 2>The email is opened and when i hit cancel, the header gets cut off as shown in image 3 ![][2]]

[image: 3>Here u can see the header gets cut off.]

Here is the css , i added to the header :

```
div[data-role="header"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 45px;
}

.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks in advance !!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but here is what i did.

As suggested in one of the stackoverflow answer, i took out the "height=device-height" from meta-tag in index.html.

But, that fixes issue for IOS 5, but still exists for IOS6.

So, this sort of fixed the issue.

http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2012-09/msg01797.html